# How to create a procedure in an oracle sql script and use it inside the script?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, procedure, sql-scripts

I want to create a **script** for my **oracle DB**, which **drops tables**. If the table does not exist, the script won't exit as fail, just print a text: "*does not exists*".

The script is the following:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE mytable';
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table dropped');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
        DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table not exists');
    ELSE
        DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' Unknown exception while dropping table');
        RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
```

I want to drop a lot of table in one script, and I don't want to write these lines more than once.

Is there any way, to write it to a **procedure or function** which gets a parameter (the name of the table), and call this procedure in that script?

Maybe something like this:

```
drop_table_procedure('mytableA');
drop_table_procedure('mytableB');
```

Or maybe a procedure, which gets an undefined size list (like in java: **String ... table names**):

```
drop_tables_procedure('mytableA','mytableB');
```

Please give me some examples.
Thanks!

Comment: Create a procedure and pass the table_name as a parameter to it. And then in an anonymous block, execute all the procedures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can declare a "temporary" procedure in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE 

  PROCEDURE drop_if_exists(p_tablename VARCHAR)
  IS
  BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||p_tablename;
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table dropped');
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
          DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table not exists');
      ELSE
          DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' Unknown exception while dropping table');
          RAISE;
      END IF;
  END;

BEGIN
  drop_if_exists('TABLE_1');
  drop_if_exists('TABLE_2');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

in `execute immediate` you need add name of database object.
here's the script

```
create table t1 (col1 int);
create table t2 (col1 int);

create procedure drop_my_table(av_name varchar2)
as
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||av_name;
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table dropped');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
        DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table not exists');
    ELSE
        DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' Unknown exception while dropping table');
        RAISE;
    END IF;

end drop_my_table;

declare
  type array_t is varray(2) of varchar2(30);
  atbls array_t := array_t('t1', 't2');
begin
  for i in 1..atbls.count loop
       drop_my_table(atbls(i));
   end loop; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below one also

```
create or replace PROCEDURE drop_if_exists(p_tablename in VARCHAR)
      IS
    v_var1 number;
    begin 
    select 1 into v_var1 from user_tables where table_name=upper(p_tablename);
    if v_var1=1
    then 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||p_tablename;
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table dropped');
    else
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' table not exist');
    end if;
    exception 
    when others then
     DBMS_Output.Put_Line(' Unknown exception while dropping table');
            RAISE;
    end;
```

Call procedure

```
    begin 
    drop_if_exists('emp');
    end;
    /
```